# Javascript replace not working in some cases

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a problem which is taking me some time, but I cannot find a solution.
This is my function in javascript:

```
var testofin = name.replace('<?php echo $nome_dispositivo; ?>' ,'');
testofin = testofin.replace('-', '' );
testofin = testofin.replace('–', '' );
testofin = jQuery.trim(testofin);
```

I take a variable in php, delete it from a string, than delete the - and – from the same string, then trim it.
It works sometimes, but it doesn't work other times, in the same webpage:[check navigation on the left](http://www.techzilla.it/microsoft-surface-pro-recensione-72428/)

The script is not working for:

– Specifiche

– Design ed Ergonomia

but it works for the other chapters, where is not present the - or the – symbol anymore. Any help is appreciated!

Thank you.

EDIT: thanx to everybody, i solved replacing the:

```
testofin = testofin.replace('–', '' );
```

with its HexCode:

```
testofin = testofin.replace('\u2013', '' );
```

Comment: it's working for me. Chrome

Comment: you could use `<?=` instead of `<? echo` (not a fix, just a suggestion). Also, since you're using PHP anyways, do the replace there. Saves the browser from doing it

Comment: Have you noticed if only the first chars are replaced and not the others? Maybe you want a global regex to replace all the occurences. It would sum up in `testofin = jQuery.trim(testofin.replace(/-/g, '' ).replace(/–/g, ''));`

Comment: `jQuery('#pagine-tz').find('li > a').each(function () {
 jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace('–',''));
});` from console replaces fine.

Comment: Have you looked at your page source? Chrome displays your n-dash as an invalid character: `testofin.replace('�', '' )` and it makes sense that *that* would fail.

Comment: Dcoder, thank you for pointing that out. I really didn't expect that. How would you suggest to solve?

Comment: @EmanueleStrano Please post an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this solution is very specific to that page, so it might not work in all cases, but it should work for the link you provided.

```
var dashChar = String.fromCharCode(8211);
testofin = testofin.replace(dashChar, '' );
```

What I did was copy the dash in "Microsoft Surface Pro – Design ed Ergonomia" and get the dashes char code, which happens to be 8211 (Extended Ascii), so the code above uses that value and replaces it.

Let me know if it works or if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved replacing the:

```
testofin = testofin.replace('–', '' );
```

With its hexCode:

```
testofin = testofin.replace('\u2013', '' );
```